# How to make as simple names vs values plot in R?

Tags: r, charts

I have the data (in a data.table) below and all i would like is to plot on the x-axis the top twenty `rn`'s and on the y-axis the corresponding `p`.

It would look like in the image below, except that i would want to somehow indicate which data point is what word from `rn`. Could also be another diagram type.

[image]

It could become like this:

[image]

```
> tdmunidt[order(tdmunidt$p, decreasing=T)][1:20]
        rn blogs news twit   sm          p      logp
 1:    the  1042 1208  181 2431 0.06695679 -2.703708
 2:   said   170 1241   35 1446 0.03982703 -3.223209
 3:   will   604  522  196 1322 0.03641171 -3.312865
 4:    one   678  413  203 1294 0.03564051 -3.334272
 5:   just   575  283  321 1179 0.03247308 -3.427344
 6:   like   576  254  239 1069 0.02944336 -3.525287
 7:    can   555  279  186 1020 0.02809376 -3.572208
 8:   time   504  245  150  899 0.02476107 -3.698483
 9:    get   380  210  244  834 0.02297078 -3.773532
10:    new   338  332  142  812 0.02236483 -3.800265
11:    now   354  182  157  693 0.01908723 -3.958736
12:   good   289  145  217  651 0.01793043 -4.021256
13:   know   363  116  166  645 0.01776517 -4.030516
14: people   299  241   95  635 0.01748974 -4.046141
15:    day   278  141  207  626 0.01724185 -4.060415
16:    but   293  293   37  623 0.01715923 -4.065219
17:   also   296  286   34  616 0.01696643 -4.076519
18:  first   278  236   68  582 0.01602997 -4.133295
19:   year   177  320   65  562 0.01547911 -4.168264
20:    and   313  164   74  551 0.01517614 -4.188031
```

Comment: For a statistical analysis of word frequency distributions the [zipfR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zipfR/) package could be useful. In particular, it contains a function `plot.tfl()` that, in my opinion, looks promising for your problem. However, I never used that package, so I can't say for sure if it provides what you want.

Comment: thanks but i guess this should be possible without having to resort to yet another package.

Comment: There are numerous options. You could try `with(tdmunidt, { plot(p, xaxt = "n"); axis(1, at = seq(rn), labels = rn) })` or `with(tdmunidt, barplot(p, names.arg = rn, las = 2) )` or `boxplot(p~rn, transform(tdmunidt, rn = reorder(rn, -p)))`, if rn is a factor.

Comment: why downvoted my question?

Answer (score 2):

`ggplot2` can make such a graph in just a few lines:

```
ggplot(tdmunidt, aes(x = reorder(rn, -p), y = p)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + xlab("") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

If other people want to play with the data here's how I reproduced it:

```
require(dplyr)

str <- "rn blogs news twit   sm          p      logp
 1:    the  1042 1208  181 2431 0.06695679 -2.703708
 2:   said   170 1241   35 1446 0.03982703 -3.223209
 3:   will   604  522  196 1322 0.03641171 -3.312865
 4:    one   678  413  203 1294 0.03564051 -3.334272
 5:   just   575  283  321 1179 0.03247308 -3.427344
 6:   like   576  254  239 1069 0.02944336 -3.525287
 7:    can   555  279  186 1020 0.02809376 -3.572208
 8:   time   504  245  150  899 0.02476107 -3.698483
 9:    get   380  210  244  834 0.02297078 -3.773532
10:    new   338  332  142  812 0.02236483 -3.800265
11:    now   354  182  157  693 0.01908723 -3.958736
12:   good   289  145  217  651 0.01793043 -4.021256
13:   know   363  116  166  645 0.01776517 -4.030516
14: people   299  241   95  635 0.01748974 -4.046141
15:    day   278  141  207  626 0.01724185 -4.060415
16:    but   293  293   37  623 0.01715923 -4.065219
17:   also   296  286   34  616 0.01696643 -4.076519
18:  first   278  236   68  582 0.01602997 -4.133295
19:   year   177  320   65  562 0.01547911 -4.168264
20:    and   313  164   74  551 0.01517614 -4.188031"

str <- strsplit(str, "\n")[[1]] %>%
    gsub("^ ?\\d+:\\s+", "", .) %>%
    gsub("[ ]+", ",", .) %>%
    paste(collapse="\n")

tdmunidt <- as.data.table(read.csv(textConnection(str)))
```

Comment: Would this have been the same?  .... aes(x = reorder(factor(rn), p), y = p ...?  In other words, using the reorder() call?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, @lawyeR. I wasn't aware of that function until I saw it in the comments above, but have included it in my answer now. Very elegant!